# How to share data between iPhone and Apple Watch using groups?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

i am new to Watchkit development and unable to find solution to share data between iPhone and iWatch, please help me
i am looking to share data using groups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can pass the data between iPhone & iWatch using groups.

Basically iWatch can not do any processing and we need to share the data. We can share data using the `NSUserDefaults`.

But for that you need to enable `Appp Groups` from capabilities section in both your project target and your iwatch app target, as showed below

[image: App Groups]

Below is the sample code to achieve that.

In your `viewController or appDelegate` file add following code

```
 NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                               initWithSuiteName:@"group.test.yourapp"];
[myDefaults setObject:@"aadil" forKey:@"name"];
```

Basically you are setting the value `"aadil"` for `"name"` variable.

Next step is to write code to retrieve that as below

```
 NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                               initWithSuiteName:@"group.test.yourapp"];
[myDefaults objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Need I put last two lines in notification .m file to get alert for iwatch?

Comment: Yes you can put it in .m file but you need to have your simulator open and that controller open.

Comment: thanks.how to show current location in iwatch simulator? any code or link?

Comment: See iwatch dont have ability to get current location but iphone do have that capability so you need to fetch the location from iphone and pass that lat long via group to iwatch and use that data to display current location in map in iwatch.

Answer (score 5):

**WARNING!** It's not working with WatchOS 2 anymore, use methods from WatchConnectivity Framework. The best is **updateApplicationContext:** which always keep the latest data alive. From Apple doc:

> Watch apps that shared data with their iOS apps using a shared group
>   container must be redesigned to handle data differently. In watchOS 2,
>   each process must manage its own copy of any shared data in the local
>   container directory. For data that is actually shared and updated by
>   both apps, this requires using the Watch Connectivity framework to
>   move that data between them.

Comment: Any other way to do so. In my case first time if user login from iphone app and watch is not running then can;t send login data to watch using send message. i need to start watch app first then open iphone app and login into them. which is quite awful. any alternative for this?