# Communication between iOS and watch OS without network

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos

In my application i need to send data from watch to iOS device without any server communication or network how can it possible, is it possible with bluetooth? The iOS device and watches are not paired.

Comment: For paired devices, the best solution is using the [WatchConnectivity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489037/how-can-i-share-information-between-my-ios-and-watch-apps-using-watchconnectivit), however for unpaired devices that's not an option. You can try to use [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth), which became available in watchOS 4.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to pair multiple watches to single iphone? Only to share the particular apps message.

Comment: Yes, several watches can be paired to a single phone, but each watch can only be paired to a single phone. Only the owners phone and watch should be paired together, so pairing a watch to someone else's phone just to share some messages is a bad idea.

Comment: You can check out the [CoreBluetooth in watchOS tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/336-core-bluetooth-in-watchos-tutorial) by raywenderlich, which uses an iPhone as a BLE device, so it should suit your needs perfectly.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out. I was looking for something like xender.