# How to get workout session data on iphone app?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchconnectivity

What is the correct way to pass the collected workout data on the apple watch to the iOS app for display? Should I do this using WatchConnectivity or is there a special way of communication designed for workout sessions.

My iOS app configures a workout and passes this configuration to the app on AppleWatch, which starts workout sessions from the received configuration. The new data on the watch appears in the workoutBuilder(_:didCollectDataOf:) method but how to pass it to the iphone?

Comment: There's no special way to communicate workout data between the watch and the phone, so just use WatchConnectivity. Have a look at [How can I share information between my iOS and Watch apps using WatchConnectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489037/how-can-i-share-information-between-my-ios-and-watch-apps-using-watchconnectivit/45489038#45489038) if you want to learn more about the topic.

Comment: Thanks, i've missed that thread.